# Allow user to shutdown PC

Tags: linux, ubuntu, lxde

Trying to shutdown my LXDE 14.04 Ubuntu from menu. Got error:

[image]

```
"GDBus.Error:org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.AccessDenied: Operation not permitted"
```

How to allow user to shutdown PC?

Comment: Sounds like https://askubuntu.com/questions/583285/lubuntu-14-10-wont-update-or-shutdown

Comment: Does running `sudo shutdown now` work for you?

Comment: 14.04 has been unsupported for almost 3 years now. Consider upgrading.

Comment: `sudo shutdown now` works fine, but how to shut down from main menu?